# Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me out with this console error ?

```
Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

This is the code I am trying and struggling with.
code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Blog from './pages/Blog';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const App = () => (
<div className='container'>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
    <Route path='/blog/:id' component={Blog} />
    <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
  </Routes>
   </div>
   );


export default App;
```

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinkg you are using version 6 of `react-router-dom`, but used a part of code that worked in 5

This should work

```
<Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/" replace={true} />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant add navigate outside a Route . Try this

`
<Route path= "/" element= {< Home/>} />

```
  <Route path= "/blog/:id" exact element = {<LandingPage/>} />
  <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/" replace={true} />} />
```

`